# Using apt-get in mac Terminal

Tags: terminal, apt, aptitude, ios

I need to install tweaks' packages on an jailbroken iPhone via SSH. But apt-get is not included in mac command line tools. I've found that brew can be used, but it doesn't seem to work when ssh'ing iPhone.

Tweaks are installed apt-get install com.author.thweakname

How do I execute it in mac Terminal?

Comment: apt-get is not a general Unix thing. It is just Debian and its derivatives. Mac is not debian (though it **may** be possible to install apt on it). Also IOS is not MAC OS.

Comment: iOS is not Unix or Linux - this should be posted on [apple.se]

Comment: a few words about iPhone is just to make things clear. Generally, this question is about bringing apt-get to mac

Comment: Have a look in [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/index_de.html).

Comment: In my question I said, that I tried brew.

Comment: @muru Are you sure that jailbroken stuff belongs there?

Comment: @phk Oh, jailbroken? Then [su]. Either way, installing stuff on iPhones doesn't belong here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I closed this question. The thing was not in mac Terminal, but in command line tools installed on iPhone. Its APT 0.7 Strict (from Cydia of course).

Comment: @muru Well, if e.g. `busybox` or similar was involved then it would somewhat belong here. AFAIK, iOS is a BSD derivative BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` is a Debian and Debian based tool for package management.

It will not run on the iPhone correctly without **major** efforts to modify the code and packages you are wanting to run/install

Answer (score 0):

I used [fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) on MacOSX in the past as a package installer, but that is many versions of MacOSX ago so might not be available anymore?

Comment: macOS does have a native package installer, see the manual for e.g. `installer` and `pkgutil`.  I'm not aware of any third-party supplier of packages for this on the scale of Homebrew or any the other projects though. It's mostly used for packages from the "App Store" I believe.

Comment: This is about IOS and not OS X/macOS.